# Add extra image field based on selected template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress development and I am looking for a high level explanation of how I can achieve the following so that I know what I need to know to achieve it.

On the screen where you enter a new page there is a drop down to select the template to use.  I want to update the page based on what template is selected.

For instance one template might use just the featured image.  Another might need 2 images.  And another 3 images and maybe some other field.

I have looked over the code for existing plugin that adds additional featured image box so I can figure that part of it out.  I am not sure how I should make it so it only updates for the selected template and where I can keep the code.

I have no exposure to php or this code base but if someone with experience can give me the general idea of what I should do then I will be able to figure out the code.  I just need to know what functions/events I need to learn.

As a side note the consumer side of wordpress is so popular that google brings back very few developer related threads and on wordpress.org I can't figure out how to just search through the codex so its a real slow process getting into the more complicated stuff.  I know that is off topic but any additional advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you with creating the templates first. From that point, you should be able to move forward with adding different content to them.

- In your wordpress active theme folder ( wp-content > themes >
  active-theme-name ) find a php file like 'page.php' and duplicate it
  giving it a different name like 'template-custom-name.php' ( a name
  related to the page you're going to apply it to should be fine )
- From that point, open the new 'template-custom-name.php' file. At the
  top, add the following line of code to the commented /* */ out code
  section. The line needs to start with the ' * ' in it and be called something like this ' *Template Name: Template Custom Name ' (Of course, named something relating to the page you're trying to apply it to.
- From that point, you can save this file in your theme directory, upload it to your server you're working on, or keep it local if you're working locally. Login to your wordpress admin, go into pages > add new. Give the new page a name, then select the page template named 'Template Custom Name' or whatever the custom name was that you gave it.

You should be able to recreate the same steps for the other two templates. That's how you would create unique templates and assign them to your page.

To help with putting in images and custom content in the page admin:

- add a plugin called 'advanced custom fields'. This is a fantastic plugin used to create custom fields for the wordpress admin so that you can conquer your next task. Here's their site, this link goes to pretty much exactly what you're looking for: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/displaying-custom-field-values-in-your-theme/ from what I can tell.

While you're on your journey of learning Wordpress, don't forget that the Wordpress Codex is a powerful tool for learning about Wordpress's powerful features. Check out the Codex here: https://codex.wordpress.org/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.  I guess I wasn't so clear.  I am looking to add extra inputs to admin section based on selected template.  I found a pretty cool addon called advanced custom fields that does it without coding so I am playing with that and having a peak at the code to try and work it all out.  It uses a conditional: if template = name then add meta box.  Think I have the rough gist of it, enough to know what to read up on anyway.

Comment: Yes, that's what I linked to in my answer. I'm glad you found it. That is the correct direction to head in.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I didn't go over it properly as I had just read the codex templating pages section.  I should not be so hasty!  I am actually not so sure about using ACF in production though as I have been reading through the forum and performance seems to be an issue.  I have become a total page speed geek now so I am going to try and find a happy medium between plugins and my own code.